# How can I get a list of all of the product Attributes?

Tags: magento2, product, attributes, template

I have some code to get the product in my block template:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$_product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');
```

Is there a method that I can call to get me a list of all of the product attributes ?

Something like :

```
$_product->getAttributes();
```

Thanks.

---

I can use this (my bad) :

```
$attrs =  $_product->getAttributes();
foreach( $attrs as $attr ){
}
```

Comment: Do you want to list out all product attributes with their respective value for that product?

Answer (score 1):

Try below code.

```
$attrs = $_product->getAttributes();

foreach($attrs as $a) {

    echo $a->getName()."\n";
}
```